# What is the correct syntax of defining role dependencies in the meta/main.yml in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

meta/main.yml

```
dependencies:
  - { role: 030.sensu-install }
```

results in:

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: The comma separated role spec format, use the
yaml/explicit format instead..
This feature will be removed in a future release. 
Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in 
ansible.cfg.
```

when `sudo ansible-galaxy install -r requirements/development.yml` is issued.

**Attempts to solve the issue**

When

```
dependencies:
  - role: 030.sensu-install
    version: 0.1.0
```

is defined, the syntax check succeeds, but the deprecation warning persists.

---

When

```
dependencies:
  - src: 030.sensu-install
    version: 0.1.0
```

is defined, `sudo ansible-galaxy install -r requirements/development.yml` is run the deprecation warning is solved, but `ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/roles/role_under_test/tests/${playbook} --syntax-check` results in:

```
ERROR! role definitions must contain a role name
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Updating the meta/main.yml according [this snippet](https://github.com/azavea/ansible-docker/blob/d5880c617faddba82f33b5d42489de4cd81e60bb/meta/main.yml#L15) as follows:

```
dependencies:
  - src: 030.firewall
    version: 0.1.0
    name: 030.firewall
  - src: 030.sensu-client
    version: 0.4.1
    name: 030.sensu-client
  - src: geerlingguy.ntp
    version: 1.3.0
    name: geerlingguy.ntp    
  - src: geerlingguy.postfix
    version: 1.1.0
    name: geerlingguy.postfix
  - src: geerlingguy.redis
    version: 1.4.1
    name: geerlingguy.redis
  - src: Stouts.rabbitmq
    version: 1.2.1
    name: Stouts.rabbitmq
```

and installing the requirements by issuing `ansible-galaxy install -r requirements/development.yml` did not return the `[DEPRECATION WARNING]: The comma separated role spec format` issue anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There is open bugfix pull request on github regarding this issue but its still unclear if its a bug or you should use **src:** instead, check the discussion.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/14612

I guess until the devs make up their minds you can ignore that warning. Moreover you are not really using comma separated syntax, so this warning should not appear in my opinion.

```
dependencies:
    - { role: 030.sensu-install }
```

should be ok.

Comment: reference to https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/14612 (+1). Issue persists when snippet `{ role: 030.sensu-install }` is used.

Comment: Regarding `I guess until the devs make up their minds you can ignore that warning`. I do not want to ignore deprecation warnings, because these could cause huge issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using private repo for galaxy then

meta\main.yml

```
---
# local copy
#dependencies:
#   - { role: '/roles/java', java_packages: java-1.8.0-openjdk }
#http
#dependencies:
#   - { role: 'git+http://gitlabserver/ansible-galaxy/java.git,master'}
#ssh
dependencies:
   - name: java
     src: ssh://git@gitlabserver/ansible-galaxy/java.git
     scm: git
     version: master
```

Note: you may need to have private key in the host for git clone